# How to use column name in active record query in Yii1

Tags: activerecord, yii, yii1.x

I need to use crypt function inside active record query.
MySQL query:

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = 'johndoe@mail.com' AND password_hash = crypt('johnspassword',password_hash);
```

I want to convert it into active record query in Yii1. My query like below. But its showing error.

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();

$criteria->condition = 'username = :username AND password_hash = :password';

$criteria->params = [':username' => $this->username, ':password' => crypt($this->password, password_hash)];

$user = User::model()->find($criteria);
```

How to use column name password_hash inside crypt function?

Comment: `$this->password_hash`? `crypt()` is PHP function so it cannot magically access data in SQL query, since it is called before query is performed.

Answer (score 0):

Here the reason for the error is below

crypt($this->password, password_hash)

password_hash is salt and its not constant, So here password_hash must contain salt value or it should be php variable